# TableViewCell borders and shadow when scroll down (or when changing from ipad to iphone)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

First, I am sorry for the title, but i'm not sure what is causing my problem!

I have set up my TableViewCells developing on an iPad (ios 9) until the borders and shadows were as I wanted them... but when I run the app on an iPhone 6 (iOS 11.3) some weird changes appeared.

[image]

This is how the screen starts, and you can see the shadow irregularity in the second cell and a square background from the third cell

[image]

This is scrolling down, all cells have the shadow and border problem.

I used a UIView inside the cell to add the spacing and the style, so the View has the shadows and the corner radius, while the cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.

It looks like the cell background went back to white for the cells that were totally or partially out of the screen...

Any Ideas? Thanks!

---

EDIT:

Thanks for the coments! I share pieces of the code below:

```
        cell.backView.layer.borderWidth = 5
        cell.backView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cell.backView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        let shadowPath2 = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.backView.bounds)
        cell.backView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.backView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.backView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: CGFloat(1.0), height: CGFloat(3.0))
        cell.backView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        cell.backView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath2.cgPath
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

So, backView is the View with all the cell's content. There are a couple of things not needed, since I was trying stuff, but as far as I know non should be the cause...

By the way, when I run the code today it looked like it should, but I didn't do anything to the tableView, I was working on a different matter completely, so the problem is not solved officially...

Also, I noticed that after coming back from a segue, sometimes, the shadows only covered the bottom half of the cell... Can that be the same problem maybe?

Comment: It looks like the shadow size is being calculated incorrectly (the "wrong" shadows appear much larger than the "right" shadows). Can you show the code that is setting the shadow?

Comment: Can you share the code for this cell?

Comment: can you share the code with us?

Comment: Try adding cell.clipsToBounds = false and cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = false.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing more than you need to do...

Assuming you've added your `backView` to your cell prototype in IB, and all the other content is contained in that view (labels, chart, etc), you can add this to your cell class:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {

    backView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    backView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    backView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    backView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 3.0);
    backView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5

}
```

which gives this result:

[image]

No need for any other code... shadows will maintain their appearance when scrolling / rotating device / etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right, I should add that code in the class, not in the controller... that helps a lot... As you now the problem is kind of random, and as for now i'm not seeing it any more... I haven't done any changes though... So I'll implement this, and if I have no problems I'll mark it as answer in a couple of days!

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was **clipToBounds**.
I unChecked it in CollectionView and CollectionViewCell and child of it.